# Swift fails to send request but Postman succeeds

Tags: ios, swift

**EDIT 2:** I ended up just switching to a POST request and putting `latitude`, `longitude`, and `deviceToken` in the body. This fixed the issue. I guess iOS will truncate headers if the query string is too long. I'd post this as an answer but it's more of a workaround than a fix.

---

**EDIT 1:** After adding some logs to the server, I found the problem. For some reason, iOS is cutting the end off my auth token. This is what's logged on the server (length 1015):

```
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImNjMTFhZWFlYmNhMjJlNzIzYzRhZDE5ZTQzNTgxNmE5ZGM4MTllMjk4OGUyMzZmYTUzYjMwNDUyYTQ2YzhkZDg2NjVlYTU4ZGJmYmY0MTIwIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxMCIsImp0aSI6ImNjMTFhZWFlYmNhMjJlNzIzYzRhZDE5ZTQzNTgxNmE5ZGM4MTllMjk4OGUyMzZmYTUzYjMwNDUyYTQ2YzhkZDg2NjVlYTU4ZGJmYmY0MTIwIiwiaWF0IjoxNTMzNzYwNjk1LCJuYmYiOjE1MzM3NjA2OTUsImV4cCI6MTU2NTI5NjY5NSwic3ViIjoiMSIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.OSu3q5Gxj6Sad5B44J1kUTHs0H9Yc86Hw0oXtm-CmXyO_NirIX3oVxvEsACGpn-4gMMFOx61pJ4mb43pTg9dhIgmgDmywv5mkzRC-pLd5PiSaq4YpxFxlbk_rXZWDXGgGeLwh9iZl7-ByusECeKdn0LrqE3X0XrEehU25OLPI-lDq_hREVMV-eE4zTAunCbhLGMbNCMYZuvEB8NwBhKZSpdoIGS1buZmiUCupUTajgkgfMAVup2ym45s_0eIPvLjcDZgVvpaUgkvUBUPVcEoz-kkL7BTQjmgz0aPLhWYA116pa8pU_lwzuBzU7T85FCy6Mqlas6sg2aGI5RFhcWpFrNHvenNJ7Hd3PlgZHj5bHXpEmQtu93-50Z1tkG4h-wOZ9vxV9WHvDDRzfUg5aivqJtje1dLVLkyb2Eov_gpxhJWHSeAK3laN7_K0YL_gXN0lPey8kMsSuX74rPlOuiKZXsooYoP2VU_4EMxJgBPtUjuBq4o4RqZulFQljLUN02iPaevL1c3Q9LBlXr81O6qhKTjRZ4M3fdxjRkODgBnarQhGdGTnpwSnMn1UtUvjjTJKlnrRxwj4nsZCQI06YHXB06GOV85-5ChB6-c1xFa_Xp
```

And in iOS (length 1079):

```
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImNjMTFhZWFlYmNhMjJlNzIzYzRhZDE5ZTQzNTgxNmE5ZGM4MTllMjk4OGUyMzZmYTUzYjMwNDUyYTQ2YzhkZDg2NjVlYTU4ZGJmYmY0MTIwIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxMCIsImp0aSI6ImNjMTFhZWFlYmNhMjJlNzIzYzRhZDE5ZTQzNTgxNmE5ZGM4MTllMjk4OGUyMzZmYTUzYjMwNDUyYTQ2YzhkZDg2NjVlYTU4ZGJmYmY0MTIwIiwiaWF0IjoxNTMzNzYwNjk1LCJuYmYiOjE1MzM3NjA2OTUsImV4cCI6MTU2NTI5NjY5NSwic3ViIjoiMSIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.OSu3q5Gxj6Sad5B44J1kUTHs0H9Yc86Hw0oXtm-CmXyO_NirIX3oVxvEsACGpn-4gMMFOx61pJ4mb43pTg9dhIgmgDmywv5mkzRC-pLd5PiSaq4YpxFxlbk_rXZWDXGgGeLwh9iZl7-ByusECeKdn0LrqE3X0XrEehU25OLPI-lDq_hREVMV-eE4zTAunCbhLGMbNCMYZuvEB8NwBhKZSpdoIGS1buZmiUCupUTajgkgfMAVup2ym45s_0eIPvLjcDZgVvpaUgkvUBUPVcEoz-kkL7BTQjmgz0aPLhWYA116pa8pU_lwzuBzU7T85FCy6Mqlas6sg2aGI5RFhcWpFrNHvenNJ7Hd3PlgZHj5bHXpEmQtu93-50Z1tkG4h-wOZ9vxV9WHvDDRzfUg5aivqJtje1dLVLkyb2Eov_gpxhJWHSeAK3laN7_K0YL_gXN0lPey8kMsSuX74rPlOuiKZXsooYoP2VU_4EMxJgBPtUjuBq4o4RqZulFQljLUN02iPaevL1c3Q9LBlXr81O6qhKTjRZ4M3fdxjRkODgBnarQhGdGTnpwSnMn1UtUvjjTJKlnrRxwj4nsZCQI06YHXB06GOV85-5ChB6-c1xFa_XpeAvmftgz9xSKCxdlvwyQRU3NYpKd0eSJedVFEniHgjjwIhg4KYillScIrgFoo5NI
```

The server token is missing 64 characters at the end.

---

I'm trying to send a GET request with several query parameters in the URL from my iOS app. Everything was working fine until I added a new parameter `deviceToken`. After that, the server responds with an auth failure. The strangest thing is: I'm logging both the auth token and the URL string and I can successfully make the exact same request from Postman without any auth errors.

This code receives a failed auth response (note that `queryString` contains `deviceToken`):

```
let escapedDeviceToken = deviceToken.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) ?? ""
let queryString = "latitude=\(location.coordinate.latitude)&longitude=\(location.coordinate.longitude)&deviceToken=\(escapedDeviceToken)"
let urlString = "\(account.serverAddress)?\(queryString)"
print("--- URL string \(account.authToken) \(urlString)")

let url = URL.init(string: urlString)!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue(account.authToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

print("--- Sending location update")
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
  if let response = response {
    print("--- response \(response.debugDescription)")
  }
  if let error = error {
    print("--- Location update failed \(error.localizedDescription)")
  } else if let data = data {
    print("--- Location update success %@", data)
  }
}

dataTask.resume()
```

And it logs this URL and auth token:

```
--- URL string 
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImNjMTFhZWFlYmNhMjJlNzIzYzRhZDE5ZTQzNTgxNmE5ZGM4MTllMjk4OGUyMzZmYTUzYjMwNDUyYTQ2YzhkZDg2NjVlYTU4ZGJmYmY0MTIwIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxMCIsImp0aSI6ImNjMTFhZWFlYmNhMjJlNzIzYzRhZDE5ZTQzNTgxNmE5ZGM4MTllMjk4OGUyMzZmYTUzYjMwNDUyYTQ2YzhkZDg2NjVlYTU4ZGJmYmY0MTIwIiwiaWF0IjoxNTMzNzYwNjk1LCJuYmYiOjE1MzM3NjA2OTUsImV4cCI6MTU2NTI5NjY5NSwic3ViIjoiMSIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.OSu3q5Gxj6Sad5B44J1kUTHs0H9Yc86Hw0oXtm-CmXyO_NirIX3oVxvEsACGpn-4gMMFOx61pJ4mb43pTg9dhIgmgDmywv5mkzRC-pLd5PiSaq4YpxFxlbk_rXZWDXGgGeLwh9iZl7-ByusECeKdn0LrqE3X0XrEehU25OLPI-lDq_hREVMV-eE4zTAunCbhLGMbNCMYZuvEB8NwBhKZSpdoIGS1buZmiUCupUTajgkgfMAVup2ym45s_0eIPvLjcDZgVvpaUgkvUBUPVcEoz-kkL7BTQjmgz0aPLhWYA116pa8pU_lwzuBzU7T85FCy6Mqlas6sg2aGI5RFhcWpFrNHvenNJ7Hd3PlgZHj5bHXpEmQtu93-50Z1tkG4h-wOZ9vxV9WHvDDRzfUg5aivqJtje1dLVLkyb2Eov_gpxhJWHSeAK3laN7_K0YL_gXN0lPey8kMsSuX74rPlOuiKZXsooYoP2VU_4EMxJgBPtUjuBq4o4RqZulFQljLUN02iPaevL1c3Q9LBlXr81O6qhKTjRZ4M3fdxjRkODgBnarQhGdGTnpwSnMn1UtUvjjTJKlnrRxwj4nsZCQI06YHXB06GOV85-5ChB6-c1xFa_XpeAvmftgz9xSKCxdlvwyQRU3NYpKd0eSJedVFEniHgjjwIhg4KYillScIrgFoo5NI 
http://192.168.1.61:80/api/updateLocation?latitude=44.0478080936615&longitude=-123.089300322125&deviceToken=fxdyzROI-vs%3AAPA91bFAdN3IR2bAxBS4rihVUCWsA1njO6RDgZ0fBDJRWvRisEKJz9I1ZTmeN6gsV85Dmg-0ZtGGqz9DSWmjZjqmyRrZ4feVBgUNPtfjALCZJM7hyScEyy02YixrW9zgcOK8sSW0JvFSrzpiPWYfdUZOt8gmU-8-NQ
```

And this is what I see on my Laravel server:

```
ERROR: exception 'League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException' with message 'The resource owner or authorization server denied the request.' in /Users/james/projects/GoNoteDev/server/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php:165
Stack trace:
  0 ./vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/AuthorizationValidators/BearerTokenValidator.php(53): League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException::accessDenied('Access token co...')
  1 ./vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/ResourceServer.php(82): League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationValidators\BearerTokenValidator->validateAuthorization(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest))
  2 ./vendor/laravel/passport/src/Guards/TokenGuard.php(110): League\OAuth2\Server\ResourceServer->validateAuthenticatedRequest(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest))
  3 ./vendor/laravel/passport/src/Guards/TokenGuard.php(90): Laravel\Passport\Guards\TokenGuard->authenticateViaBearerToken(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  4 ./vendor/laravel/passport/src/PassportServiceProvider.php(251): Laravel\Passport\Guards\TokenGuard->user(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  5 [internal function]: Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider->Laravel\Passport\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  6 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/RequestGuard.php(55): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  7 ./app/Http/Middleware/AuthApi.php(13): Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard->user(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  8 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\AuthApi->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  9 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  10 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  11 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  12 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  13 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  14 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), '1000', '1')
  15 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  16 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  17 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(561): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
  18 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(520): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  19 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(498): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  20 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  21 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  22 ./app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  23 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\Cors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  24 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  25 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  26 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  27 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  28 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  29 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  30 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  31 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  32 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  33 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  34 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  35 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  36 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  37 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  38 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(149): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
  39 ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  40 ./public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  41 ./server.php(21): require_once('/Users/james/pr...')
  42 {main}
```

Then I take the exact auth token and URL from the iOS logs and paste it into postman:

[image: Postman success]

And it succeeds. My Laravel server log after the postman request:

```
[2018-08-08 14:17:38] INFO: -123.08930032212 44.047808093662 fxdyzROI-vs:APA91bFAdN3IR2bAxBS4rihVUCWsA1njO6RDgZ0fBDJRWvRisEKJz9I1ZTmeN6gsV85Dmg-0ZtGGqz9DSWmjZjqmyRrZ4feVBgUNPtfjALCZJM7hyScEyy02YixrW9zgcOK8sSW0JvFSrzpiPWYfdUZOt8gmU-8-NQ 2
[2018-08-08 14:17:38] INFO: Sending PN to fxdyzROI-vs:APA91bFAdN3IR2bAxBS4rihVUCWsA1njO6RDgZ0fBDJRWvRisEKJz9I1ZTmeN6gsV85Dmg-0ZtGGqz9DSWmjZjqmyRrZ4feVBgUNPtfjALCZJM7hyScEyy02YixrW9zgcOK8sSW0JvFSrzpiPWYfdUZOt8gmU-8-NQ
[2018-08-08 14:17:39] INFO: Success
```

Is this a bug in the iOS HTTP code? Why would the request only fail when sent from iOS? It seems like iOS is either stripping or corrupting my `Authorization` header.

A couple additional things:

- The `deviceToken` parameter is not used by the auth middleware on the server.
- Removing the `deviceToken` parameter causes the request to succeed consistently.
- Replacing `&deviceToken=` with `&someOtherNameHere=` causes the same problem (it doesn't seem at all related specifically to the `deviceToken` param).

Comment: First step is to use something like Charles Proxy, or logging from the server, to figure out exactly what iOS is sending and what the server receives.

Comment: @JonShier I'll try to get some server logs of the request.

Comment: Ok. Found the problem, but I'm not sure what the solution is. Added an edit.

Comment: Have you checked the content of `account.authToken`. It seems your server is receiving the exact content you set in `account.authToken`.

Comment: @OOPer I'm logging `account.authToken` on iOS and the request auth header on the server. The server is receiving the auth token minus like ~50 characters at the end.

Comment: Then you should update your question. The auth token in your _And it logs this URL and auth token:_ and your _And in iOS:_ are exactly the same, no _minus like ~50 characters at the end_ .

Comment: They aren't the same. The token logged on the server ends with `Fa_Xp` but the token logged in iOS ends with `Fa_XpeAvmftgz9xSKCxdlvwyQRU3NYpKd0eSJedVFEniHgjjwIhg4KYillScIrgFoo5NI` which is what is in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I might be mis-reading your old EDIT part as _And in iOS:_ meant _server side log when sent from iOS_.

Comment: In edit 1, the first token is logged by the server and the second token is logged by iOS here: `print("--- URL string \(account.authToken) \(urlString)")`